# При подключении visual studio к mysql ничего не появляеться используя ADO.Net EDM

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework

[image: пробую добавить]

[image: Спустя пол секунды само закрывается, результата ноль]

Пробую подключиться к MySQL но ничего не получается, даже ошибок не выдает просто само закрывается(Спустя пол секунды само закрывается на этапе выбора EntityFramework, результата ноль).

Comment: Проверьте включен ли сервер. Установлен ли провайдер для mysql. Проверьте соединение при создании. Укажите явно пароль для пользователя root (у вас там сейчас режим integrated security, который не поддерживается mysql) В общем причин масса может быть, это всё можно долго гадать отчего у вас не завелось. А особенно весело, если у вас не одна ошибка, а две - и вам придётся перебирать разные сочетания вариантов. Удачной отладки в общем.

Comment: У вас база данных называется user?